# How can I stop a Java jar file application that was started with this command

Tags: application, java

In order to run a game server (minecraft) I start it by running this command in CentOS:

`java -Xms512M -Xmx1G -jar minecraft_server.jar`

But I have no idea how to stop this file from running. I assume it has it's own internal command but considering it might be started in background and running for a very long time, how can I stop this Java command?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of ps and kill to stop the particular process.

You would first do `ps -aux | grep minecraft` to get the process number - which is the second field, first number.

Then you can issue `kill $PID` to send SIGTERM to the process and have it gracefully shutdown.

Comment: deleting mine, yours looks nicer (yes, I know about a non drastic kill, was just being quick).

Comment: Then check, and if that doesn't stop the process then enter kill -9 $PID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following 2 files to start/stop **service.jar**

**start.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PID=0
if [ -f './pid' ]; then
    PID=$(cat ./pid)
fi

if ps -p $PID > /dev/null
then
   echo "Service with $PID is already running"
else
    nohup java -jar ./service.jar > service.out 2> errors.txt < /dev/null & PID=$!; echo $PID > ./pid
fi
```

**stop.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ -f './pid' ]; then
    PID=$(cat ./pid) && kill -15 $PID
fi
```